# How to restrict a table from being dropped if its view is still in use

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we restrict a table from being dropped if its any column is used in some view?
If yes then please suggest me how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option when creating [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)s (and some other objects such as Functions<sup>1</sup>) to specify `WITH SCHEMABINDING`.

So long as at least one view exists with this option specified and referencing your table, you will not be able to drop the table.

If you get into the habit of specifying this option wherever possible (i.e. for all such objects) then you'll get what you want.

There's no way to specify it from the "table end" though.

---

<sup>1</sup>But, *grr* only for natively compiled [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)s. Instead for non-natively compiled procedures we still have to put up with the rules of deferred name resolution with not even an opt out option available.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
DENY DELETE ON OBJECT::dbo.table_to_deny TO restricted_user;
```

Comment: This only kinda sort of deals with the issue at hand. It only prevents a single user and misses the criteria that it not be allowed if there is a view referencing the table.

Comment: In the answerer's defense, the question is too broadly worded to preclude this as an answer.   It doesn't specify that the solutions needs to programmatically detect that a table's column is used by a view.